# IntelliJ JavaFX project cannot user bintray repo

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to use the bintray repo in my `JavaFX` project using the `IntelliJ` ide.

I've tried to go `Settings -> Maven -> Repositories` and adding this 2:

```
https://jcenter.bintray.com/
https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter
```

None of them work and I can't find any `pom.xml` or `settings.xml` or any maven settings.
What I can do ? Importing the `JAR` is not a solution. These `.jar` need other 3-4 libraries like `Apache` library and others and I don't want to import them manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use maven, then you can just add this repo to your `pom.xml` or `settings.xml` manually:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jcenter</id>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Note: in `settings.xml` you need to put this into [profile](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Profiles).

**Update**: probably the easiest way to start using maven for building your project, is to create empty maven project using [`mvn archetype:generate`](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/generate-mojo.html) command, and then copy your sources to created project `src/main/java` folder.

Comment: I can't find any pom.xml or settings.xml

Comment: Check your project root for `pom.xml` and `~/.m2/` for `settings.xml`. But probably you don't use maven to build your project, if you don't have `pom.xml`.

Comment: Is there a way to enable maven or to recreate the project ? My project need to be JavaFX

Comment: Updated answer about this.

Comment: That link for JavaFx is out of date. JavaFx is now part of Java 8. See http://www.korecky.org/?p=1296 or http://fxapps.blogspot.be/2014/02/a-minimal-java-8-project-using-maven.html

Comment: So in intellij I create a maven project ?

Comment: No, you need to import existing maven project after you create it with `mvn archetype:generate`.

Comment: That means I have to import maven-archetype-plugin first

Comment: Ok, I managed to install maven and run mvn `archetype:generate` and created a maven project, I've put <respositories></repositories> block, now how can I import the library ?

Comment: Nvm, I have solved the problem. Thank you for all your answers